# Tailwind how to overlap div in small device

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I have 2 div and it's just in small mobile devices. What I need to do is I need to overlap the first div on it like a slider.

Something like this on small device this first div overlap the second one.

[image]

I have created a tailwind play : https://play.tailwindcss.com/mXUSLad3GV (need to only do on small device)

Right now both div are showing side by side in row but I don't get how can I overlap like this.

Comment: did you try to use z index. this is done by z index. you conditionally change the z index,whicever is greater will be shown on top. seems like z index task, I do not know what I am missing. here is the tailwind-z index https://tailwindcss.com/docs/z-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`z-index`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bZog.png) property of tailwind-css.And use `relative` and `absolute` display format and change it's visibility for different screens.

### Logic behind overlaping `div`

Have parent `relative` having `z-index` value less than the child `absolute` div which will be used for navbar.

##### Code:

```
    <div class="h-screen relative z-0 flex bg-gray-500">
      <div class="text-4xl">
        The main content of the file and it has it's content all over the page
        and i want to build a navbar on top of this
      </div>
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 z-10 bg-green-400 w-1/3">
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Mobile Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

##### Code Link: [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/gWk390mobZ)

##### Output:

[image]

---

### Logic behind responsive `Sidebar`

If you are aiming to build `responsive sidebar` which overlaps only on the `mobile screen` but would be normal div in the `large screen` then follow the below code.

#### Code:

```
    <div class="md:bg-yellow-400 h-screen relative z-0 flex bg-gray-500">
      <div class="invisible md:visible bg-blue-400 w-1/3">
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Desktop Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-4xl">
        The main content of the file and it has it's content all over the page
        and i want to build a navbar on top of this
      </div>
      <div
        class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 z-10 bg-green-400 w-1/3 md:invisible"
      >
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Mobile Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

##### Code link : [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/N8yjIUHXVT)

#### Output in large device:

[image]

#### Output in smaller device:

[image]

---

### Implementation of this logic in your code

*Assumption ⚠ : Any devices less than `md:`breakpoint is mobile. You can change it according to your requirement*

#### Code: [Tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Oxt7YYl0HT)

*I have updated the code to have possible explanation comments*.

##### Output on Large Screen

[image]

##### Output on Mobile Screen

[image]

---

### Extra : Toggle mobile navbar using hamburger menu

#### Output in small device with `hamburger menu`

[image: Enter description]

#### When clicked on `hamburger menu`

[image]

#### Code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="bg-yellow-400 h-screen relative z-0 flex">
      <div class="hidden md:block bg-blue-400 w-1/3">
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Desktop Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-4xl pl-24 md:p-0 main_content">
        The main content of the file and it has it's content all over the page
        and i want to build a navbar on top of this
      </div>
      <div
        class="mobile_navbar absolute inset-y-0 left-0 z-10 bg-green-400 w-1/3 hidden"
      >
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Mobile Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="md:hidden space-y-2 absolute hamburger_menu inset-y-0 left-0 p-4"
      >
        <span class="block w-8 h-1 bg-white"></span>
        <span class="block w-8 h-1 bg-white"></span>
        <span class="block w-8 h-1 bg-white"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document
        .querySelector(".hamburger_menu")
        .addEventListener("click", () => {
          console.log("Hello");
          document.querySelector(".mobile_navbar").classList.toggle("hidden");
        });

      document.querySelector(".main_content").addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("Touch me");
        console.log(
          document
            .querySelector(".mobile_navbar")
            .classList.contains("hidden") == false &&
            document.querySelector(".mobile_navbar").classList.toggle("hidden")
        );
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```